# CLUI - fancy progress bar in nodejs console - is there an easy way to update it?

Tags: node.js, console, node-modules, console.log

There is an existing example that updates progress bar in place: https://github.com/nathanpeck/clui/blob/master/examples/progress.js (60 lines in total)

There is much simpler example directly in  the readme: https://github.com/nathanpeck/clui/blob/master/README.md (4 lines only)

```
var clui = require('clui');

var Progress = clui.Progress;

var thisProgressBar = new Progress(20);
console.log(thisProgressBar.update(10, 30));
```

So I've added `setInterval` so that it updates the progress. I've also added line to `clear` the console and new `console.log` with each interval:

```
var clui = require('clui');

var Progress = clui.Progress;

var value = 50;

var thisProgressBar = new Progress(20);

console.log(thisProgressBar.update(value, 100));

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    value++;
    // console.log("Updated value: " + value);

    process.stdout.write('\033c'); // clearing the console
    console.log(thisProgressBar.update(value, 100));

    if (value === 100) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 500)
```

In the example with countdown spinner - https://github.com/nathanpeck/clui/blob/master/README.md#spinnerstatustext - **I don't have to** `clear` the console and do `console.log`.

Ideally I would like to do just `thisProgressBar.update(value, 100)` and the **progress bar should be updated in place easily**... Not sure my approach is good, and before I start replicating 60 lines solution I want to ask!

Opened GitHub issue as well for extra visibility: https://github.com/nathanpeck/clui/issues/22

Tried creating https://runkit.com/embed/umrs8pxg9geg demo but it is not real console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm [log-with-statusbar package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-with-statusbar). How about this:

```
var clui = require("clui");
var log = require("log-with-statusbar")();

var Progress = clui.Progress;
var value = 50;

var thisProgressBar = new Progress(20);
// console.log(thisProgressBar.update(value, 100));
log.setStatusBarText([thisProgressBar.update(value, 100)]);

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  value++;
  // console.log("Updated value: " + value);
  log("Updated value: " + value);

  // process.stdout.write('\033c'); // clearing the console
  log.setStatusBarText([thisProgressBar.update(value, 100)]);
  // console.log(thisProgressBar.update(value, 100));
  if (value === 100) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 500);
```